# OpenUI5: Where is the data gone, loaded by sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel()?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have been googling and testing around for quite a few days with no success. If someone could give me a hint to point me into the right direction, then I would greatly appreciate that.

**What is my target:** to get some data from an OData service and show it in an UI5 oTable. Later on, I will have to do the CRUD-operations, but for now the aim is just to show the data successfully.

**What I have got so far:** I have an MVC project. I have created an OpenUI5Controller.cs, whose purpose is to represent an ODataService:

```
public class OpenUI5Controller : Controller
{
    private MyEntities myEntities = new MyEntities();

    public JsonResult GetAllContragents()
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Contragent> contragents = myEntities.Contragent.OrderBy(x => x.Code);

            // for now, take the first 100 only
            contragents = contragents.Take(100);

            var jsonData = new
            {
                rows = contragents.ToList()
                //rows = "123"
            };

            var res = Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return res;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LoggingService.WriteLog("Error in OpenUI5Controller.GetAllContragents()", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I try to consume the data like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel('/OpenUI5/GetAllContragents', {
            //maxDataServiceVersion: '2.0',
            json: true,
            skipMetadataAnnotationParsing: true,
            // none of those callbacks is ever triggered, even the requestFailed...!?
            requestSent: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            requestFailed: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            requestCompleted: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            batchRequestCompleted: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            useBatch : false
        });

var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
        var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
        var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
        var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
        var vfewgvfewgv4 = oModel.getProperty('contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv5 = oModel.getProperty('/contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv6 = oModel.getProperty('Contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv7 = oModel.getProperty('/Contragents');
debugger;
```

When stopping at this breakpoint, I see this in the Chrome Developer Tools:
[image]

Moving further, I came accross [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3825615) and tried to read() those contragents:

```
oModel.read('/Contragents', {
            success: function (event) {
                debugger;
                // event.root I guess should be the received data as jsonString

                // As I guess, I will have to get it and give it to oModel.oData manually, or am I wrong? I guess this would cause update(), delete()... calls to fail later on. Anyways...

                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel); // https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3746588 - seems not to work like this
                if (withJsonModel !== true) {               https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/12/32241b99d7437ba3614698d53dfa4b/content.htm
                    oTable.setModel(oModel);
                    oTable.bindRows("/");
                    //oTable.bindRows("/rows");
                    oTable.placeAt('tblContragents', "only");
                }
            },
            error: function (event) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

Here, neither success, nor error callback gets ever triggered.

After this read() attempt, I have again:

```
var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
        var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
        var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
        var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
        var vfewgvfewgv4 = oModel.getProperty('contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv5 = oModel.getProperty('/contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv6 = oModel.getProperty('Contragents');
        var vfewgvfewgv7 = oModel.getProperty('/Contragents');
```

and I see this:
[image]

After that, I have `oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table(...);`

Finally, I try this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
        //oTable.setModel(oModel); // or maybe should be this one directly?
        oTable.bindRows("/Contragents");
        oTable.placeAt('tblContragents', "only");
```

As a result, I get an empty table.
I suppose I should tell you what I see in Fiddler as well: I see this request: 1    200 HTTP    localhost:55714 /OpenUI5/GetAllContragents/$metadata
As a result in the TextView of the response section, I see the data as json, that I need to show in the table.

How to make it work and show the data in the table?

**edit from 02.02.2017:** I have 1% of progress. After some more and more testing and googling, I decided to try it like this.

First of all, some time ago (can't really remember when), after seeing [a good example for OdataServices](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint), I decided to create a dedicated controller like this:

```
public class ContragentsController : ODataController
{
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();


    //public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetContragents()
    public string GetContragents()
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Contragent> contragents = db.Contragent.OrderBy(x => x.Code);

            // for now, give me first 100
            contragents = contragents.Take(100);

            var jsSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            var rows = jsSerializer.Serialize(contragents.ToList());

            //var jsonData = new
            //{
            //    rows = model
            //};

            //var res = new System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult();
            //res.Data = jsonData;
            //res.JsonRequestBehavior = System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

            return rows;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //...some errorLogging
            return null;
        }
    }
```

After that, I changed the call to ODataModel() like this:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(BASE_HREF + 'odata/', {
            //maxDataServiceVersion: '2.0',
            json: true,
            skipMetadataAnnotationParsing: true,
            // those callbacks still do not get called at all
            requestSent: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            requestFailed: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            requestCompleted: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            batchRequestCompleted: function (a, b, c) {
                debugger;

                var trgrwg = oModel.getData();
                var vfewgvfewgv = oModel.getProperty('/');
                var vfewgvfewgv2 = oModel.getProperty('/rows');
                var vfewgvfewgv3 = oModel.getProperty('rows');
            },
            useBatch : false
        });
```

The whole drama is that SapUI5 runs a request for $metadata, before making the actual request to odata/Contragents and so on. As expected in this case, I see in Fiddler, that the server 404-s to that request: http://localhost:55714/odata/Contragents/$metadata and it doesn't reach the moment to make the request to Contragents. I know, that I will have to change the source of the library somewhere in order to prevent this $metadata request from running, which I don't want to do. So in Fiddler's Composer, I tried the following: localhost:55714/odata/$metadata and it returned some xml with the desired metadata (maybe indeed it is important, but I haven't understood yet why). Next step was to modify the call to sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(); as shown above. The great thing after all that is the fact, that oModel.read('/Contragents', {...}); showed signs of life! Now, the success callback gets called and in event.root I get those contragents as json string. **And then what?** I tried oModel.setData(JSON.parse(event.root)); but it gave me this error:
[image: this error]

Also, if I manage to get it working this way, I don't quite understand, will the CRUD methods of oModel work? oModel.setData()-ing is something familliar to me from the time when I was playing around with JSONModel():

```
oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(dataForGrid); // this works like a charm
```

But using JSONModel() means, that I cannot use the insert(), update()... methods of sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(), because JSONModel(); does not provide us with them, which is normal, as long as I get dataForGrid via a standard $.ajax() call.

**edit2:** While debugging, I noticed, that the method ContragentsController.GetContragents(); gets called twice and in the console, I see this error message:
[image: this error message]

**edit3:** Following [the good example for ODataService](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint), I added a "selection" method to the controller like this:

```
// GET: odata/Contragents(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Contragent> GetContragents([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.Contragent.Where(contragent => contragent.Code == key));
    }
```

In Fiddler, it 404-s and does not get called at all no matter if i Compose it like this: `http://localhost:55714/Contragents(2)` or like this: `http://localhost:55714/odata/Contragents(2)`

Couple of minutes later, I've got couple of % progress. I looked even closer in the tutorial and I noticed something, which made me change the "selection" method to this:

```
// GET: odata/Contragents(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Contragent> Get([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.Contragent.Where(contragent => contragent.Code == key));
    }
```

Now, when I Compose this request: http://localhost:55714/odata/Contragents(2), it now does not 404, but does 406 Not Acceptable. I came across this error code some time ago and I didn't understand well what is the reason for it and how is it related to ODataServices.

I just reminded myself what does 406 mean and it turns out, that every method on the controller must return a json result as string. Because, SapUI5 sets Accept-Type to "application/json".

Comment: I see your OData service is running on localhost, port 55714 - how do you expect that creating the ODataModel as you did will work? 'new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel('/OpenUI5/GetAllContragents'

Comment: in the success method call back, what does `event` contain?
I have never tried CoffeeScript. But sure can look into it.

Comment: @Chris N - I am a beginner when talking about SapUI5 and OData services. That's why I am asking. :) But if I make a pure $.ajax() call to /OpenUI5/GetAllContragents‌, I get the data. Pls, tell me what's the difference in OData service with SapUI5 - I suspect this is my major misunderstanding. Also, Fiddler shows, that a successful call is made and those contragents are returned as json by the server.
@Sunil B N - neither of the callbacks gets called at all. Those in new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({...}) as well as in oModel.read('', {...}), so I don't know what does `event` contain